# Chrome extension: create new window in depends on window presence

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I create a new window in my Chrome extension like this:

```
    chrome.windows.create({
      url: 'https://example.com',
      focused: false,
      state: "minimized"
    }, function(hiddenWindow) {
       var code = "console.log('Some JS code goes here');"
         chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info) {
            if (info.status === 'complete') {
              chrome.tabs.executeScript(hiddenWindow.tabs[0].id, {
                  code: code
                },
                function(results) {
                  console.log(results);
                });
            }
          });
        });
```

It is possible somehow to do this one:

1. First time we create a window with one tab inside (like in my code above)
2. Then each time we check if this window is not closed by user
3. If the window still exists, then open a new tab in this window and close the previous tab.
4. If this window no longer exists, then do it all over again starting from #1

Will be grateful for any help and ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the id of the window in a variable (global, for example) and use `chrome.windows.get` - when the window is closed the API will return an error in `chrome.runtime.lastError`. Also, instead of closing the previous tab it seems simpler to navigate the existing tab to a new URL.

Now, the above scheme would require us to use an elaborate cascade of callbacks at worst or Promises at best, but since it's 2019 let's use the modern **async/await** syntax instead with the help of [Mozilla WebExtension polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill/releases).

```
let wndId;
const wndOptions = {
  focused: false,
  state: 'minimized',
};
const code = `(${() => {
  console.log('Some JS code goes here');
}})()`;

async function openMinimized(url) {
  const w =
    wndId &&
    await browser.windows.get(wndId, {populate: true}).catch(() => {}) ||
    await browser.windows.create({url, ...wndOptions});
  wndId = w.id;
  const [wTab] = w.tabs;
  if (wTab.url !== url) browser.tabs.update(wTab.id, {url});
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async function onUpdated(tabId, info) {
      if (tabId === wTab.id && info.status === 'complete') {
        browser.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(onUpdated);
        resolve(browser.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code}));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
openMinimized('https://example.com').then(results => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Notes:

- onUpdated listener checks tabId to process only this tab
- onUpdated listener unregisters itself
- `code` can be written as normal JS with syntax highlight inside an IIFE in a template string
- How to use the polyfill: download `browser-polyfill.min.js` from its official repo on [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/browse/webextension-polyfill/dist/), save in your extension directory, and load it just like any other script in your extension, for example, as a background script in manifest.json:

  ```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["browser-polyfill.min.js", "background.js"]
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I need!